# MVI+MVVM: who should store input data?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to implement a simple screen, which idea is the following:

1. It receives a list of `Item`s from another screen. Each item contains only `id`;
2. It displays those items in a `ListView`;
3. Each item in the `ListView` is represented by `LsitViewItem` class, which adds optional `name` property to the `id` property of the `Item`;
4. Thus each cell displays `id` and additionally it displays an input field, which allows user to input `name`;
5. There's also a button on the screen. When user presses this button all `Item`s with their `id`s and optianally (if user has input any) `name`s are sent to backend.

I want to implement this screen via MVVM architecture, combined with the MVI concept. I'll call `Model` from the MVI concept `State` just to distinguish with the `Model` from MVVM. With this concept I need a single source of data. I also need to propagate back to "smth" all user inputs to the "name" fields.

It looks like my model is a backend. Another words it is a Retrofit service implementation or some wrapper class around it.

With this configuration I don't understand the following:

1. Who should stote the initial `Item`s list from the previous screen? A `ViewModel` or `Model`?
2. If Model then do I need to propagate all `name`s changes back to the Model (according to the MVI concept)? If yes, then what would be the difference between `ListViewItem`s (presentation layer) and `Item`s (Model layer)?
3. Is my interpretation of the `Model` correct or I can omit it? Another words can I have MVVM without `Model`? So, all my `Item`s are stored within `ViewModel` and when user presses the button they're just send to the backend through some class, which is not part of MVVM architecture at all?

Other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Model. In MVI, it is a function that takes an intent and returns a state (or model). Are you asking whether you should cache the list of items in the VM or in the data-layer? I used to store it in the data-layer with MVP. With MVVM I store it in the VM.

Comment: whether to feedback the name from the view to the state is tricky. It can get very heavy. You need to decide whether that is actually part of the business logic or it can be handled by the View (view as defined in MVVM). I know that this would break the principle of the "single source of truth" for the state but I ended finding myself having to make compromises while using MVI.

Comment: @kingston Yes, by model here I mean the "data-layer". I finally found it useful by myself to introduce interactor into MVP and store the user input there. So, for the point 1 of my question: I store the selected items from the previous screen in data layer, then pass it through interactor in order to add user input, then through presenter, which simply converts it into State and passes to the View.